# Updating array on child 2, from child 1

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**child 1** has an array of items

**child 2** needs to pass an item object to child 2 to update child 2s item array.

How can I pass this item object to the parent from child 2, and then send it back down to child 1.

**parent render:**

```
 <Child1  currentItems={currentItems} />
 <Child2 />
```

**child 1:**

```
 const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState(
    props.currentItems
  );

  // call this from child 2 via parent
  // pass item property to be able to update currentItems
  function updateItem(item: Item) {
    const indexOfItem = currentItems.indexOf(item);
    currentItems[indexOfItem] = item;
    setCurrentItems(currentItems);
  }
```

**child 2:**

```
  function handleItemClick(item: Item) {
    // use this to send to updateItem on child 1 via parent
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Child1  currentItems={currentItems} />
```

From that code it seems you already have the `currentItems` in the parent, you should just move the `updateItem` function from `Child1` to the parent, pass it `Child2` and then call it inside `handleItemClick`.

```
function Parent() {
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]);

  function updateItem(item: Item) {
    const indexOfItem = currentItems.indexOf(item);
    currentItems[indexOfItem] = item;
    setCurrentItems(currentItems);
  }

  return <>
    <Child1 currentItems={currentItems} />
    <Child2 updateItem={updateItem}/>
  </>
}
```

```
function Child1({currentItems}) {
  // there is no need for another currentItems state here
}
```

and in Child2:

```
function handleItemClick(item: Item) {
  updateItem(item);
}
```

Also note that your `updateItem` function will not trigger a re-render. You should create a new array so that React can tell it has changed. Try `setCurrentItems([...currentItems])`

Comment: Great answer! Although, I would argue that `Child2` should have an `onItemClick` prop instead to let the parent component decide what a click actually means. But that's somewhat a matter of opinion.